# Nestjs Roles Decorator: Crazy behaviour with getting user out of payload data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, decorator

I am just trying to implement my Roles Decorator in Nestjs. So far it went pretty well, until I wanted to compare the user of the payload data from the jwt-token to the required role. I can't explain how this is possible, but it is only possible to get the user and role out of the payload data, if i let the function return always true. After I set a condition the user is undefined. How is this even possible?

Here is my (shortened) user controller, where I use the Decorator:

```
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}
  private readonly logger = new Logger(LoggingService.name);

  @Post('/create')
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10);
    createUserDto.password = hashedPassword
    return this.userService.createUser(createUserDto);
  }

  @Roles(Role.SUPERADMIN)
  @Get('/')
  showUsers() {
    return this.userService.getUsers();
  }
```

And here is the roles decorator, with condition:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoggingService } from 'src/services/logging/logging.service';
import { User } from 'src/user/schemas/user.schema';
import { Role } from '../role.enum';
import { ROLES_KEY } from '../decorators/roles.decorator';
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}
  private readonly logger = new Logger(LoggingService.name);

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {

        const roles = this.reflector.get<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, context.getHandler());
        // If there is no Roles-Decorator, just pass through
        if (!roles) {
          return true;
        }

        this.logger.debug("REQUIRED ROLES: ", roles)
        

        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const userRole = request.user?.roles;
        const userID = request.user?.sub;
        this.logger.debug("ROLES GUARD USER", userID);
        this.logger.debug("USER ROLE", userRole);


        // Else, check the request header if it matches

        if (roles.includes(userRole)) {
            return true;
        } else { return false }

  }

}
```

Logging output (when I try to access the route):

```
[Nest] 4460  - 25.11.2021, 18:56:33   DEBUG [LoggingService] REQUIRED ROLES: 
[Nest] 4460  - 25.11.2021, 18:56:33   DEBUG [LoggingService] superadmin
[Nest] 4460  - 25.11.2021, 18:56:33   DEBUG [LoggingService] ROLES GUARD USER
[Nest] 4460  - 25.11.2021, 18:56:33   DEBUG [LoggingService] undefined
[Nest] 4460  - 25.11.2021, 18:56:33   DEBUG [LoggingService] USER ROLE
[Nest] 4460  - 25.11.2021, 18:56:33   DEBUG [LoggingService] undefined
```

But when I do this:

```
// Else, check the request header if it matches

        // if (roles.includes(userRole)) {
        //     return true;
        // } else { return false }

        return true;
```

The logging output is this:

```
[Nest] 39888  - 25.11.2021, 19:00:14   DEBUG [LoggingService] REQUIRED ROLES: 
[Nest] 39888  - 25.11.2021, 19:00:14   DEBUG [LoggingService] superadmin
[Nest] 39888  - 25.11.2021, 19:00:14   DEBUG [LoggingService] ROLES GUARD USER
[Nest] 39888  - 25.11.2021, 19:00:14   DEBUG [LoggingService] 619962ad86e412dc06983a0e
[Nest] 39888  - 25.11.2021, 19:00:14   DEBUG [LoggingService] USER ROLE
[Nest] 39888  - 25.11.2021, 19:00:14   DEBUG [LoggingService] superadmin
```

The control-flow is top to bottom, right? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you happen to have a provider **anywhere** in your application like `{ provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: RolesGuard }`?

Comment: Yes, I provide it in the users.module:
`@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository, LoggingService, {
    provide: APP_GUARD,
    useClass: RolesGuard,
  }],
  exports: [UserService]
})
export class UsersModule {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `APP_GUARD` in **any** module that is registered by the application registers the guard as a global guard, that will run before every request. What I would do is register two global guards, one for the `JwtAuthGuard` one for the `RolesGuard`, and implement a `@JwtSkip()` decorator, that tells the `JwtAuthGuard` that it can skip authentication on this route (would be the same for the `RolesGuard` as it shouldn't have any roles associated with it

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Following that logic, I simply tried to remove the JwthAuthguard and only use the RolesGuard for the users.controller. But still the same output:

`[Nest] 43020  - 25.11.2021, 21:53:19   DEBUG [LoggingService] REQUIRED ROLES: 
[Nest] 43020  - 25.11.2021, 21:53:19   DEBUG [LoggingService] superadmin
[Nest] 43020  - 25.11.2021, 21:53:19   DEBUG [LoggingService] ROLES GUARD USER
[Nest] 43020  - 25.11.2021, 21:53:19   DEBUG [LoggingService] undefined
`

Comment: The `JwtAuthGuard` is what sets `req.user`, because `passport` is what sets `req.user`. Otherwise, there's no `user` as a part of the request object, that's why I suggested making the `JwtAuthGuard` global and make sure it runs before the `RolesGuard`

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution according to your input. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution!

I had not registered the RolesGuard in a global context. So I went ahead and put

```
app.useGlobalGuards(new RolesGuard(new Reflector()));
```

in the main.ts.
It then suddenly worked. And I modified the condition to pass the Guard as follows:

```
// Else, check the request header if it matches

        if (roles.some(r => r == userRole)) {
            this.logger.log("ROLES GUARD: PASS")
            return true;
        } else { 
          this.logger.error("ROLES GUARD: DENIED")
          return false 
        }
```

Hope this helps anyone!